# jQuery (window).scrollTop() in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scope, scrolltop

I'm trying to work through a problem I'm having using the value of (window).scrollTop() as a variable. Ultimately what I need to do is get the value returned from the scroll at a *specific* point (within if statement) so it can be used globally within an event, however I need *only* the value it returns at this point, so it does not change when scrolled. I have used setInterval() so the script can check if it is at this point or not. Here is a simple version of my code:

```
var $windowend;

var $elone = $('.element-one');
var $eltwo = $('.element-two');


setInterval(function(){

    var $left = $elone.css('left');

    if ($left >= 500) {

    // return number here 
    $windowend = $(window).scrollTop();

    }
}, 100);


$(window).scroll(function(){

    $elone.css({
        'left': $(window).scrollTop()
    })

    $eltwo.css({
    // use number returned here
        'left': $windowend
    })

});
```

As you can see, when the first element gets to or past 500px, I need to return the value of scrollTop, to check how far the window has scrolled thus far. However I need only the first value it returns (so it does not change afterwards even if the scrollTop() increases or decreases)

I hope this is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
var $windowend = "auto";

var $elone = $('.element-one');
var $eltwo = $('.element-two');


setInterval(function(){  

    var $left = $elone.css('left');

    if ($left >= 500 && $windowend =="auto") {

        // return number here 
        $windowend = $(window).scrollTop() + "px";

    }
}, 100);


$(window).scroll(function(){

    $elone.css({
        'left': $(window).scrollTop()
    })

    $eltwo.css({
    // use number returned here
        'left': $windowend
    })

})
```